# Monitor Amazon RDS bandwidth usage

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

How do I monitor the RDS bandwidth usage to know how much data is being transferred out? My RDS is accessible outside of the VPC for certain clients and I want to monitor it

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Cost Explorer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/cost-explorer-what-is.html) to view data transferred. The tool is straight forward to use, I pulled up data transfer using the following filters:

- **Service**: Relational Database Service
- **Usage Type**: search for "DataTransfer" and select the zones you wish to track

Have a play with the different options to get the data that works for you. The only downside is the stats are only updated once every 24 hours. If you are willing to bear the cost, you may want to use the cost explorer API for real-time cost explorer data updates:

https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/11/introducing-the-aws-cost-explorer-api/

[CloudWatch Metrics](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/rds-metricscollected.html) can give you a live or historical view of bandwidth usage, but does not have a metric which tracks the amount of data used.